# Having error when using jquery.corner.js with jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jquery corner to get curvy quicklaunch in my sharepoint 2010.
But i geting eeor "object doesn't support this property or method.
Any ideas if this version are compatible.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you able to use any jquery function at all? This way we could determine if the issue is in the jquery registration, in the jquery.corner one or in the specific function you may be using. Also... Can you please post the script tags you are using for registration? I think I may have a clue, but I need to have a look at the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are you haven't got the two references to the .js files right or in the right order. If you post your code we can verify this, but usually that error indicates an incorrect reference.

Comment: Thanks guys
Sig i actually figured it out earlier. As i use
.ms-quicklaunchouter{
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
position: relative;
-pie-lazy-init:true;
-pie-poll:true;
behavior: url("/_layouts/PIE/pie.htc"); 
background-color:#85B2ED;
 
}

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this might not exactly be the answer you are looking for, but for such a simple task I'd try to avoid complex and error prone scripting solutions.

**Update:** Corrected the code due to a bug in the previous version and added a red border for better readability.

Instead I'd go with a simple CSS 3 solution which is supported by all modern Web browser like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome/Chromium, Apple Safari and Opera. As for Internet Explorer it is supported with IE 9+ (with a change in your masterpage of "X-UA-Compatible" to "IE=8;IE=EmulateIE9").

In this scenario the CSS would look like:

```
#s4-leftpanel-content
{
    border: none !important;
    position: relative;
}
#s4-leftpanel-content .ms-quicklaunchouter .ms-quickLaunch
{
    border: 5px solid red; // this is just for better readability
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

However, if you need to support legacy Web browsers like IE 8 and below I'd rather use CSS3 Pie http://css3pie.com/ instead of jQuery, like this:

```
#s4-leftpanel-content
{
    border: none !important;
    position: relative;
}
#s4-leftpanel-content .ms-quicklaunchouter .ms-quickLaunch
{
    border: 5px solid red; // this is just for better readability
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    behavior: url("/_layouts/styles/pie.htc");
}
```

CSS3 Pie is an awesome library to bring several missing CSS 3 features to IE and I'm using it frequently to overcome several IE limitations without requiring scripting hacks.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sig Weber: Do you have experience in using this lib in sharepoint? How about performance? Do you faced with javascript (or other) bugs when using it in sharepoint? Thank

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with SharePoint & IE 8/9 without major issues. Performance of IE is sluggish as usual, no matter if with or without CSS3 Pie ;-) As for the "bugs" it depends on which elements you use it. Sometimes it requires to add a position:relative on the particular element to make pie work as expected. Same goes for the two -pie properties I've added in my example above. Needs some experimenting but once you know about those quirks it's as simple as using pure CSS3 with modern Web browsers.

Comment: Beware that htc files won't cross domains without some network tuning.

Comment: Thanks guys.and thanks sig but i need to support IE7 and IE8.Will this work on this browsers without issues?

Comment: Yes, I've been using CSS3 Pie with IE 7, 8 and 9 without problems.

Comment: Sig i just tried it with my sharepoint site using the CSS above but no luck i have followed the instruction and linked to the PIE file.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my CSS which I posted of the top of my head without verifying in a test/development virtual machine. I've now corrected my original answer with a working, and tested, CSS example.